# How to use ActiveRecord Transactions within Parallel multi-process blocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm trying to update entries in Postgres in parallel using ActiveRecord in Rails, my code looks something like this.

```
# new_records is the result of an ActiveRecord query.
Parallel.each(new_records, in_processes: 8) do |record|
            ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
                ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
                    edit_record(record)
                    record.save!
                end
            end
end
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

Can anyone help me out with how to correctly run ActiveRecord transactions in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a similar problem when trying to do a parallel for `ActiveRecord` connection pool. I solve it by changing the worker type, from processes to threads. According to the `parallel` documentation, it is recomended to use threads if you are going to use explicity the `ActiveRecord` connection pool.

Your code could be rewriten to:

```
Parallel.each(new_records, in_threads: 8) do |record|
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
       ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
           edit_record(record)
           record.save!
        end
   end
end
```

I hope you find this helpful.